# Lazy Operator C# for own Data Access

Tags: c#, winforms, entity-framework, orm

I'm currently building a medical scheme type application in winforms. I have implemented a lazy loading approach to the data access. I can't use an ORM like EF or nHibernate, so I have implemented it with own logic. I have multiple fields on a class eg. Package which contains navigational properties such as `List<Treatment>` which should get all the treatment covered for this package. Is it bad practice to wrap the entire list with lazy, it gets instantiated something like this:

```
        Package package = new Package()
        {
            PackageID = record.GetInt32(0),
            Name = record.GetString(1),
            CoverageAmount = record.GetDecimal(2),
            PackageStatus = (Status)record.GetInt32(3),
            AvaliableFrom = record.GetDateTime(4),
            AvaliableTo = record.GetDateTime(5),
        };

        package.Policies = new Lazy<List<Policy>>(() =>
        {
            return GetPoliciesByPackageID(package.PackageID);
        });

        package.Treatments = new Lazy<List<Treatment>>(() =>
        {
            return GetTreatmentsByPackage(package.PackageID);
        });

        return package;
```

When I want all the treatments I have to call package.Treatments.Value, this feels wrong somehow. Is this approach frowned upon.

Answer (score 1):

Lazy instantiation is not bad practice per se, however if you are exposing expensive (in terms of time taken to acquire results) values via properties then this is bad practice. Properties are designed to be quick-to-access exposure to part of an object's state. If you are acquiring data expensively then expose a method.

Comment: Currently the method `GetTreatmentsByPackage` and such do a call to a repository which queries a database. So it might be quite "expensive".

Comment: Is lazy behaviour what you want at all then? The Lazy<T> inner instance will never be changed once evaluated so if the database changes you will keep returning stale data from the lazy.

Comment: So the inside of the lazy `() =>
        {
            return GetTreatmentsByPackage(package.PackageID);
        }` will only be evaluated once. Then on repeat calls, what does it do? Is the data store somewhere? I think i have a different understanding, probably wrong.

Comment: Yes, it's evaluated once only (warning: not thread safe - see AsyncLazy<T>). So once it's evaluated it stores the result and returns it every time Value is queried.

Comment: Thanks man, I did not know that. will look into AsyncLazy<T>. Seems my design wasn't as rock solid as I thought. There are a couple of object that use the same logic.

Answer (score 0):

The fact that the data is loaded lazily seems to be an implementation detail. As such, I would encapsulate it.

```
public class Package
{
    private readonly Lazy<List<Policy>> _lazyPolicies =  ...

    public List<Policy> Policies
    {
        get { return _lazyPolicies.Value; }
    }
}
```

If you'd like to emulate what NHibernate does, you could use a [proxy](http://www.oodesign.com/proxy-pattern.html)

Here's a simple (thread unsafe) proxy:

```
public interface IPackage
{
    List<Policy> Policies { get; }
}

public class Package
{
    public List<Policy> Policies { get ; set; }
}

public class PackageProxy
{
    private readonly Package _package;
    private readonly Database _db;

    public PackageProxy(Package package, Database _db)
    {
        _package = package;
        _db = db;
    }

    public List<Policy> Policies
    {
        get
        {
            if(_package.Policies == null)
                _package.Policies = GetPoliciesByPackageID(package.PackageID);
            return _package.Policies;
        }
    }

    private List<Policy> GetPoliciesByPackageID(int id)
    {
        _db...
    }
}

// usage

IPackage package = new PackageProxy(new Package(), db) { /** set properties **/ };
```

Comment: I like this approach , only problem I see with this. As far as I know readonly only allows assignment within the constructor. which I don't use as these objects are purely data holding with many fields and properties. The constructor will be quite long, for personal preference I don't like

Comment: @RiaanvanRooyen Well, if their data is going to be loaded lazily, then they're not as "dumb" as you initially thought they would be. Another option would be to do this via a proxy (or dynamic proxy), the same way NHibernate does it. The DTO would have "dumb" properties, and the proxy would wrap around the DTO, expose the same interface, but call into the database when the property getters are called.

Comment: thank you. I'm still learning currently studying Software Engineering is South Africa. I appreciate the advice I'll definetly look into the dynamic proxy. Do you have any resources that show the insides of Entity-Framework or NHibernate?

Comment: @RiaanvanRooyen I do not, I've read that this is the technique they use, but I don't remember where. It should be easy to find though. Also, NHibernate uses [Castle DynamicProxy](http://www.castleproject.org/projects/dynamicproxy/) to generate proxies of your objects dynamically at runtime. I added an example of a non-dynamic manually written proxy to demonstrate what happens behind the scenes.

Comment: Thanks, this is really well laid out. Gives a good idea. much appreciated I would upvote but not enough reputation. first question